# Delayed insert with JPA , Spring orm, Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

Ok, this is a very strange behavior with the technologies already mentioned, i have a controller which calls a service and this calls a dao the entity passed to persist have a field with an annotation `@Column nullable = false, unique = true`, when when i run the test for the dao or the service and a duplicated value is inserted an Exception is thrown 
`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` which is ok, is the expected behavior. but when i run the web app, the exception is thrown after the service has finished it's execution no when the dao is being executed. so this has forced me to catch the exception in the controller, not in the service.

1. controller   //start
2. service //continues
3. DAO   //continues  (but an exception should be thrown at this point)
4. service // finishes  (a try catch is surrounding the dao, but no exception is thrown).
5. controller //exception is thrown.

i added some logs in each method so i can see that the

> insert into ...

sentence is executed once the service call has finish.

Thank you.

***EDIT***

this is the xml transaction definition.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>

        <tx:method name="crea*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="obtener*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" isolation="DEFAULT"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.company.service..*.*(..))"
        id="txPointcut" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="txPointcut" />
</aop:config>
```

And this are 2 snippets of code, the first is catching the exception.

```
package com.company.service.tarea.ventas.impl

    public Producto obtenerSiExisteDuplicadaClave(String clave) {

        try{
            return productoService.buscarPorClave(clave);
        }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
            log.error(e.getMensaje());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This code is not working

```
com.company.service.tarea.almacenpt.impl

    public void creaEntradaProduccion(Entrada entrada, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug("creaEntradaProduccion");


            entradaService.peristeEntrada(entrada);

        if(log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug("persistido...");
    }
```

The exception is thrown until the code has executed and returned the execution to the controller, it reaches the log "persistido".

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. Persisting en entity only associates it to the persistence context. The exception will be thrown when the insert statement is executed, and the statement is executed when the persistence context is flushed (which happens automatically, either before a query is executed, or before the transaction is committed).

Your test probably works because the transaction in the test is started when the DAO call is made, and committed right after. Whereas in production, the DAO call is made as part of an existing transaction, started when the service has been called, and committed when the service method returns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, According to my transaction xml file it should start in the beginning of the method in the service and flushed or finished at the end of the same method, so the exception should be thrown in this method boundaries.

Comment: And that's exactly what happens: the tx interceptor sees that your service method is transactional, so it starts a transaction, then calls the service method, then commits the transaction, which fails with an exception, that you catch in your controller.

Comment: U r right, but what makes me confused it is that in others services the exception is working as expected, this is, catching the dao's exceptions. not in the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

@OJVM : You are catching a specific Exception (EmptyResultDataAccessException). Is this the same exception which is escaping your try/catch block.
To identify the same, put a generic Exception block. Log it.
Once identified the specific Exception which escapes this block add it here.

Ex:

```
package com.company.service.tarea.ventas.impl

public Producto obtenerSiExisteDuplicadaClave(String clave) {

    try{
        return productoService.buscarPorClave(clave);
    }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
        log.error(e.getMensaje());
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e.getMensaje()); // e.getMessage() ; // Once caught put handle this exception also specifically
    }
    return null;
}
```